# PC monitor flickers/resets when washer motor switches on or off

Tags: voltage, emc, interference, emi-filtering, emf

My room is next to our laundry and I've recently got a new PC monitor. I've noticed each time the motor in the washing machine is switched on **or** off, my monitor flickers/resets. The monitor is 32" but it isn't that power hungry (~40 W). The washing machine is a top loader. The monitor flickers/resets only when the motor is switched on/off and not when it's running. The dryer does it too. Lamps and lights don't dim though. My old monitor is fine too. I've tried turning on a kettle in the laundry and that has no effect.
​

Does anyone know what might be causing this? Is it EMI interference or is it voltage drop?

Comment: yes, emi interference. The PSU of monitor is low cost, no filter or damaged. As well the loundry machine does not provide any interference suppressor.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Is this something that can be fixed with a ferrite choke?

Comment: If you think of clamp-on ferrite choke, you are making a common mode choke, which is good for high frequencies. What you experience is a low frequency _conducted_ disturbance, for which you would need a good Pi-filter (C-L-C). Most likley not worth the effort. Is your power supply to the monitor external by any chance? Connected to the same outlet as the signal source?

Comment: @winny The power supply to the monitor is not external. It's just a cheap Viewsonic monitor. By signal source, I suppose you mean the graphics card? In that case, yes, it's on the same socket as the PC. But if you were referring to the washing machine, then no. The washer is in the laundry. The washer and the monitor are on the same branch though.

Comment: Get yourself a small UPS and that should cover it...

Comment: If you disconnect the PC VGA/DVI cable but let the monitor display some OSD while your washing machine turns on/off, can you still see the disturbance?

Comment: @winny The screen switches off when no source is detected. I can try using my laptop next time though (I already did my laundry today). What would each scenario mean?

Comment: Not not detected, but not connected! No effect once signal is disconnected would mean it’s transmitted though the DVI/VGA cable.

Comment: @winny Yes, that's what I mean. If there's no source connected/detected, the screen automatically switches off. So I'll need to use a laptop to test what you advised. But what if it does/doesn't continue to flicker?

Comment: Still no, you need to differentiate between connected but no signal and not connected. Your monitor may very well be more susceptible to CM disturbance on your signal input than mains. You would probably be better off putting a choke or better yet, a Pi filter on your washing machine.

Comment: Sounds like the power line has major spikes injected by the motor or relays involved. The new monitor has a poor-quality power supply.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Is it something a choke could fix?

Comment: @winny I'll try a choke and see how it goes.

Comment: Reminds me of this video: https://youtu.be/r-V_Z3bD_PA

Answer (score 1):

If it only happens when the motor starts, it may be voltage drop when the Starting Capacitor is in the single phase motor winding circuit. That then could be related to your supply for the house being under sized, but it could also be indicative of a loose connection somewhere, and that sort of thing tends to get worse over time. You may want to call an electrician.

Comment: It actually happens when the motor stops as well. Would this still suggest a loose connection?

Comment: Yes. Any sudden change in loading.